# Unable to connect to MSSQL server through Node, while Intellij connection works (MacOS)

Tags: javascript, sql-server, intellij-idea

I'm running into a strange behaviour where I'm unable to connect to an instance of MSSQL server running locally on docker when using a Node js script, but I can connect to it using Intellij's built-in JDBC connector.

This is the script:

```js
import mysql from "mysql"

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'sa',
    password : 'P@55w0rd!',
    database : 'ml_project',
    port: 1433,
    connectionLimit: 15,
    queueLimit: 30,
    acquireTimeout: 1000000
});

connection.connect(function(err) {
    if ( !err ) {
        console.log("Connected to MySQL");
    } else if ( err ) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});

connection.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution', function (error, results, fields) {
    if (error) throw error;
    console.log(results[0].solution);
    connection.end();
});
```

Which outputs the following error:

```
Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.
    at Protocol.end (/Users/IoannouK/ml_project/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:112:13)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/IoannouK/ml_project/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:94:28)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/IoannouK/ml_project/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:526:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:322:22)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1187:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/Users/IoannouK/ml_project/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/Users/IoannouK/ml_project/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
    at Connection.connect (/Users/IoannouK/ml_project/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:116:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/IoannouK/ml_project/dist/mysql.js:17:12)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1156:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1176:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47 {
  fatal: true,
  code: 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST'
}
/Users/IoannouK/ml_project/dist/mysql.js:27
        throw error;
        ^
```

And this is the settings panel in my Intellij which works:

[image]

I have also tried connecting to a remote database, as well as using a python script, but I received the same results.

Comment: so inetllij works with SQL SERVER and can you exlplain why you want to use mysql driver to connect to the same server?

Comment: Is it MSSQL or mySql ? if it is MSSQL then change the require to mssql on top..

Answer (score 0):

```
const express = require("express");
var sql = require("mssql");


const multer = require("multer");

var config = {
  user: "jsudjac",
  password: "$#jsuapple",
  server: "10.1.4.125",
  database: "JSULLC_Test",
};
var dataSource = {
  user: "********",
  password: "*******",
  server: "10.2.2.2",
  database: "Stock_Test",
};


const dbconn1 = sql.connect(config, (err) => {
  if (!err) {
    console.log("Connected to the database");
  } else {
    console.log("Problem in connecting to database");
    console.log(err);
    console.log("testing");
  }
});
```